# View array results in SUMPRODUICT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I view the full TRUE/FALSE results from Array1?

F9 only returns the 275 formula result

[image]

Comment: Highlight just the ISNUMBER portion of the formula within the formula bar and press F9. There is still a limitation to how many entries can be displayed that way, but if might be sufficient in your case. Alternatively, you can use the Evaluate Formula window to step through the formula.

Comment: Unfortunately the F9 only provides the formula result. The Evaluate Formula doesn't work either as you can't see the full data set. I'm sure I have seen SUMPRODUCT with TRUE/FALSE results showing in the formula bar somewhere before

Comment: Could you share the formula contained in the cell (as text) so we can experiment with it?

Comment: '=IF(AN14081=FALSE,
"",
SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(IT!$A$6:$A$126,Data!$AS14081)),ROW(IT!$A$6:$A$126)-5))'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Evaluate Formula tool on the Formulas ribbon. It only shows four rows of text in the dialog (despite many people having been asking Microsoft for years to make that box bigger), but at least you can scroll and it will show all entries.